# Cron job to create backup of database and mail to me

Tags: cron, cron-task

```
MAILTO=goeltushar4391234@gmail.com

54 1 * * * pg_dump -U postgres db_name > ~/backup/bck.bak

* * * * * ~/backup/bck.bak
```

I am using the above cron job in PostgreSQL. The backup is created successfully, but mail is not coming. Moreover, I am confused from which ID I will receive mail. How can I fix this?

Comment: The second crontab entry is trying to run `~/backup/bck.bak` as a command every minute. That's probably not what you want.

Comment: Your script to send the mail is missing. Can you share this? And it is not placed in crontab.

Comment: can anyone share the script to send mail?